# How to convert an integer value into 'n' digit ascii byte array in java

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

Is any method to convert an integer value into 'n' digit ascii byte array in java.  Like

```
IntToBytes( int value, int digits );

int a = 1234;
IntToBytes( a, 4 );
results will be byte array of {1, 2, 3, 4}

IntToBytes( a, 5 );
results will be byte array of {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I searched in internet no method found.  Please help me

Comment: mathematics would be a good and fast approach

Comment: @KevinEsche do you mean 'divide and reminder' method

Comment: Note that `'a'` etc are not `byte`s, they are `char`s. Do you mean `(byte) 0`, or `(byte) '0'`, or something else?

Comment: you mean array of chars? ascii are symbols that are mapped to specific numbers. and what output do you expect from input: `IntToBytes(a, 7)`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I edited the question

Comment: @MaxG I mean array of ascii bytes

Comment: @Krishna what are ascii bytes? can you give reference?

Comment: @MaxG I mean array of ascii values (8bit)

Comment: So do you just want to separate the digits of the number?  I'm unsure what ASCII has to do with your method from the code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain an array with the values of the digits in decimal notation, you can create a function like this one:

```
public static byte[] intToBytes(int number, int digits) {
    byte[] results = new byte[digits];
    /* Start at the end of the array. i.e. 1234, should be converted to {1, 2, 3, 4} */
    for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        results[i] = (byte) (number % 10);
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return results;
}
```

If what you want is an array with the ascii value of each digit, you can use `String.format` and convert the String to the array of bytes.

(1234 should be converted to {'1', '2', '3', '4'}. The ascii values would be {49, 50, 51, 52}

The code could be:

```
public static byte[] intToBytes(int number, int digits) {
    String format = "%0" + digits + "d";
    String numberAsString = String.format(format, number);
    char[] numberAsCharArray = numberAsString.toCharArray();
    byte[] result = new byte[digits];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberAsCharArray.length; i++) {
        result[i] = (byte) numberAsCharArray[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution for me !

Answer (score 1):

I think your precise question is how to convert an `int` number representation into a series of its digits in decimal notation.
I do not know of any **existing** (i.e. library) method for this, but you could easily write your own using one of the obvious ways. One of them would be to repetitively take remainder from division (a.k.a. Horner's method). The other one could be to convert the `int` to `String`, and then convert this `String`s characters to `bytes` by casting.

Comment: Fastest is `byte digit = a - a / 10`.  Remember to modify `a` after each iteration with  `/= 10`.

Comment: @LukeSamuel What do you mean by 'byte digit = a - a / 10'

Comment: @Krishna: Luke Samuel  means the Horner's method; see my post and google for this name.

Comment: My bad, it should be just `byte digit = a - a / 10 * 10` or `a % 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Within apache commons lang there is the class `org.apache.commons.lang3.Conversion` which has the method [longToByteArray](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Conversion.html#longToByteArray%28long,%20int,%20byte[],%20int,%20int%29). That might be helpful for what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `String.format()` function

the example may be helpful for you

```
    String s = String.format("%06d", 1234);
    System.out.println(s.toCharArray());
```

hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

Straight from my project Euler library. :)

The algorithm does a`mod 10` to get the last digit, then divides by `10` to `shift` the number right and remove the last digits. This repeats until zero. In my algorithm I return an array, so I use `log10` to get the exact number of digits. You can optionally just stick this in a while loop and divide by `10` until equals `0` and append `mod 10` to a List.

```
public static int[] getDigits(long n) {
    final int digits = numDigits(n);
    final int[] d = new int[digits];
    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        d[i] = (int)(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    return d;
}

public static int numDigits(final long n) {
    return (int) Math.log10(n) + 1;
}
```

It should be pretty trivial to adapt this to return an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud use the operation modulo.
You have to create a digits size char array and then, iterating from the end, insert value%10 - '0' (last digit converted into a char) in that position and dividing value by 10 in each iteration. When value = 0 you just have to insert '0' into the remaining positions.